# Camel 3/4 decommission String type in DataFormatClauseProcessorDefinitionType>> for Marshal/unmarshal

Tags: apache-camel, marshalling, java-17

I'm working on a JDK17 upgrade for my application and wanted to utilize Camel 4.0.0-M2 as suggested by the Camel website.  So, for example, in the code, we marshal the data with String UTF-8 and set the headers, as below,

### from(builder.toString()) .routeId(routeId) .noStreamCaching() **.marshal().string("UTF-8")** .setHeader("inboundFilename", simple("${file:onlyname}"))

So when I call ".marshal().string(..), I get an error. Because the string method has been decommissioned, I'm looking for an alternative method that returns the Type so that I can set the header.
My task is to connect to SFTP, read the file, marshal it, and then process it.
I couldn't find much information on this on the internet. Thanks in advance!!